# entityframework code-first migrations paket

Tags: entity-framework-6, nuget, paket

The nuguet package for EntityFramework (6.1.3) installs some tools that you can execute from the nuget package manager console (like **AddMigration**, **Update-Database**, etc.). Those are available if you use nuget and the appropiate .ps files are loaded.

I'am resolving my project & solution dependencies with [paket](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) instead of nuget, so those commands are not available to me.

Are there any alternative to execute those scripts without having to go back to nuget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ErikEJ mentioned, you can use migrate.exe from the command line. Unfortunately (from the docs):

> All the utility is designed to do is execute migrations. It cannot generate migrations or create a SQL script.

So you can run any existing migrations, but you can't create any new ones with this tool. That makes migrate.exe a pretty poor replacement for the tools EF provides in the Package Manager Explorer.

I tried manually importing the EntityFramework.psd1 file in the Package Manager Console:

`PM> Import-Module ".\packages\EntityFramework\tools\EntityFramework.psd1"`

While this made the Enable-Migrations command available, running it produced the following error:

> No packages installed.
>
> The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'Foo'.

I'm guessing that this is all going to work better with EF7. But for now, it looks like I'll either have to ditch paket altogether, or have a frankenstein of both Paket and Nuget to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you an run migrate.exe from the command line, it is included in the NuGet package in the Tools folder.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the Paket issue [Entity Framework code-first migrations](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/issues/2662):

The EF commands wouldn't appear in the VS console until I've added version_in_path: true in paket.dependencies:

```
nuget EntityFramework ~> 6.2 version_in_path: true
```